# Change background color of rows which are present in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have data in the `A` and `B` column. `B` column's data is mostly duplicates of `A`'s data, but not always. For example:

```
A
Budapest
Prague
Paris
Bukarest
Moscow
Rome
New York

B
Budapest
Prague
Los Angeles
Bukarest
```

I need to search the `A` column if the values in `B` exists there. If a row matches, I need to change the row's background colour in `A` to red or something.

What function do I need to use, and how?

Sorry, I'm a newbie in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells in column A. Create a new conditional format based on a formula (Click Conditional Formattting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format).

Use this formula

```
=COUNTIF($B:$B,A1)
```

Click the <kbd>Format</kbd> button and select a format for example a fill color. Click OK.

[image]